# Pass zero fetch row to another condition

Tags: java

This is my servlet :

```
for (int i=0 ; i<studentID.length ; i++){

    System.out.println("studentID: "+ studentID[i]);

    FreeBean free = new FreeBean();
    PresentationBean present = new PresentationBean();
    StudentBean student = new StudentBean();

    int SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
    int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
    Date SVFreeDate = free.getFreeDate();
    Date EXFreeDate = free.getFreeDate();

    List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);
    Object[] array = null;
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {

    array = (Object[])(list.get(k));
    System.out.println("tryy "+ k);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

       System.out.println("try "+ j + "and "+ array[j]);
       System.out.println("apa ni" + array[7]);
    }// iterate over the Object array
   } // iterate k  

   String studentName = (String) array[7]; // I am getting NPE here
   String projectTitle = (String) array[8];
   String SVName = (String) array[11];
   String EXName = (String) array[13];
   String day = (String) array[15];
   Time start = (Time) array[16];
   Time end = (Time) array[17];
   Date date = (Date) array[3];

   if ( studentName== null ) {

   list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getOtherFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);

   SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
   EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();

   studentName = (String) array[15];
   projectTitle = (String) array[17];
   SVName = (String) array[12];
   EXName = (String) array[14];
   day = (String) array[5];
   start = (Time) array[6];
   end = (Time) array[7];
   date = (Date) array[10];
   }//if takde masa yang sama

 out.println("<tr>");
 out.println("<td>"+ studentName+"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ projectTitle +"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ SVName +"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ EXName +"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ day +"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ start +"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ end+"</td>");
 out.println("<td>"+ date+"</td>");
 out.println("</tr>");       
 }//student loop
```

Based on above code, `GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i])` will pass the values in DAO to match the `supervisorID` and `examinerID` `availabilityID` .

In some cases, the `supervisorID` and `examinerID`will not have same `availabilityID`. Thus, I want to handle it with the a `if` condition. It will return NPE on `String studentName = (String) array[7];` because in DB, there is ZERO rows fetched. That is why it enters NPE.

My idea is to handle it thru the `if ( studentName== null )`. It will use examiner's availableID as substitute but it is not working out. It will always return NPE. It did not even pass the `if` condition.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the size of the result set before assuming `array` contains a value:

```
// declarations
String studentName;
String projectTitle;
String SVName;
String EXName;
String day;
Time start;
Time end;
Date date;

List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);
if (!list.isEmpty() {
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {

    array = (Object[])(list.get(k));
    System.out.println("tryy "+ k);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

       System.out.println("try "+ j + "and "+ array[j]);
       System.out.println("apa ni" + array[7]);
    }// iterate over the Object array
   } // iterate k  

   studentName = (String) array[7];
   projectTitle = (String) array[8];
   SVName = (String) array[11];
   EXName = (String) array[13];
   day = (String) array[15];
   start = (Time) array[16];
   end = (Time) array[17];
   date = (Date) array[3];
} else {
   list = (List<Object[]>) GenerateScheduleDAO.getOtherFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i],studentID[i]);
   array = (Object[])(list.get(k));

   SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
   EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();

   studentName = (String) array[15];
   projectTitle = (String) array[17];
   SVName = (String) array[12];
   EXName = (String) array[14];
   day = (String) array[5];
   start = (Time) array[6];
   end = (Time) array[7];
   date = (Date) array[10];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked well for `if (!list.isEmpty())`. As the value is passed to `else`, I am getting NPE on `studentName = (String) array[15];`

Comment: @user6308605, you have to assign `array` after reassigning `list`. See my update.

Comment: if I only add the array declaration, I will get an error `k` is not found.. so i added again the loop.. I am still getting NPE at the same place

Comment: @user6308605 You're right, but I'm not sure why you're looping to begin with. Are you trying to get the last row specifically? If so, no need to loop, just use `list.get(list.size() - 1)`. As for the NPE, I'm guessing `getOtherFree()` is still returning an empty result set.

Comment: `list.get(list.size() - 1)` what does this mean?

Comment: @user6308605 it means return the element at the last index.

Comment: I guess the problem is, it does not get any value from `studentID[i]` . I dont understand why..